# What's the replacement of svelte/register for Svelte 4?

Tags: svelte, svelte-4

I have this project [svelte-mpa](//github.com/kokizzu/svelte-mpa), what's that I tried to upgrade to svelte-4, but [svelte/register](//svelte.dev/docs/svelte-register) already deprecated on svelte-4. What's the proper replacement of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nevermind, just use `svelte/compiler` works, change

```
require('svelte/register')
```

to

```
const compile = require('svelte/compiler').compile
```

then change

```
const renderedSvelte = require(path + '.svelte').default.render()
```

to

```
const renderedSvelte = compile(path + '.svelte')
```